# How to align label on same line as form?

Tags: forms, label, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]I have the following code for login screen using bootstrap. Please help in aligning the label in the same line as the form input field.

```
<div class="container">  
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Existing Customer</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="user">User Name:</label>
        <div class="control-group">
        <input type="text" class="textbox" id="user">
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="textbox" id="pwd">
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>      
    </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
        <legend>New Customer</legend>    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi use table which solves your alignment issues.
-------------------------------------------------------------
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">  
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Existing Customer</legend>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="user">User Name:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="control-group">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" id="user">
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label class="control-label" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" id="pwd">
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <div class="controls">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Log In" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>      
</div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <legend>New Customer</legend>    
 </div>
 </body>
```

i think you should take css from ui expert and move forward in your project. the page
   lay out should be designed as the developer only should be able to use(apply) the css in 
   the UI layer

Comment: This helped once i add Login button also on table <tr>&<td>. But, the button is left-alighned. How do I fit it to centre?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code using Bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Existing Customer</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="user">User Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="text" class="textbox form-control" id="user">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="pwd">Password:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="text" class="textbox form-control" id="pwd">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Log In" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <legend>New Customer</legend>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the respective fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G2cgf/

Answer (score 0):

Submit a margin-left to the button, like this:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Log In" style="margin-left: 15px;"/>
```